# Emoji Puzzle - UNESCO World Heritage Sites

Tags: knowledge, visual, rebus, emoji

[image: UNESCO WORLD HERITAGE SITES EMOJI PUZZLE]

Emoji Puzzle - UNESCO World Heritage Sites

Created by myself during Covid-19 lockdown. I've posted an image because emoji rendering as text are not working too well.

Comment: Can you verify the solution for 11.? If so, I think the puzzle is complete and you can accept the answer (that will give you 2 additional reputation and none to me, since it's a community wiki). *Muchas gracias* for making the puzzle.

Comment: Done ! ( i think ) You are very welcome .. Cheers !

Comment: @Omar - It doesn't look like the answer has been accepted yet. (Unless there is a lag time I am unaware of.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

An attempt to gather all correct solutions as a community wiki.

1 (found by [Jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/96728/11110))

> ⬇⬇ = Angel + fall + fall = [Angel Falls](https://whc.unesco.org/en/list/701/)

2 (found by [Chronocidal](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/96769/11110))

> = Eye + Full (moon) + toe (of a foot) + war (medal) = Eiffel Tower

3 (found by [Jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/96728/11110))

> g = Mountain + (Kung) fu + G = [Mount Fuji](http://whc.unesco.org/en/list/1418)

4 (found by [Lanny Strack](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/96725/11110))

> j = Stone + hen + j = [Stonehenge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stonehenge)

5 (found by [Glorfindel](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/96724/11110))

> = [Blue Mosque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sultan_Ahmed_Mosque) in Istanbul

6 (found by [Jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/96728/11110))

> o = Kill + eye + mango + jar + O = [Kilimanjaro](https://whc.unesco.org/en/list/403)

7 (found by [Glorfindel](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/96724/11110))

> = [Uluru / Ayers Rock](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uluru) (2 ears → Ayers + Rock)

8 (found by [Chronocidal](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/96769/11110))

> = The (Leaning) Tower of Pisa

9 (found by [JMP](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/96739/11110))

> ☕ = Statue of Liberty (lie-bee-tea)

10 (found by [Lanny Strack](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/96725/11110))

> = [(Great) Smoky Mountains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Smoky_Mountains)

11 (found by [Chronocidal](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/96769/11110))

> 1000  = Gran(d), [Adder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vipera_berus)
>  [Granada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granada)

12 (found by [Lanny Strack](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/96725/11110))

> ⚱ = [Vatican (City)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vatican_City)

13 (found by [Lanny Strack](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/96725/11110))

> ☔ = [Pyrenees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrenees)

14 (found by [JMP](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/96739/11110))

> = Great Barrier Reef (Beer-Ear)

15 (found by [Glorfindel](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/96724/11110))

> o⛽ = [Galápagos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gal%C3%A1pagos_Islands) Islands

16 (found by [Glorfindel](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/96724/11110))

> ‍♂️‍♂️‍♀️‍♂️‍♂️‍♀️‍♀️‍♂️ = [Kremlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow_Kremlin) (ice cream → Krem + a Lin(e) of people)

17 (found by [UnidentifiedX](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/96726/11110))

> = Yellowstone National Park

18 (found by [Kramii](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9603/kramii))

> ‍✈️  = [Ghee cops (cheops) pyramids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Pyramid_of_Giza)

19 (found by [JMP](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/96739/11110))

> = Rockies (Rock-Eyes)

20 (found by [Mathias711](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/96736/11110))

> = [Easter Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_Island)

Comment: I think in future these should be made from the start for these sorts of puzzles. Otherwise the page just gets spammed with answers adding a single one.

Comment: Especially since there are now 17 answers for a question with 20 parts ^

Comment: Thank you.. I totally agree :).  11 confirmed . Thank you all and well played :)

Answer (score 8):

Two to get started:

5:

> the [Blue Mosque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sultan_Ahmed_Mosque) in Istanbul

15:

> [Galápagos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gal%C3%A1pagos_Islands) Islands (gal + ape + o + gas – that might be a typo?)

and another one:

7:

> [Uluru / Ayers Rock](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uluru) (2 ears → Ayers + Rock)

and one I'm not so sure about:

16:

> [Kremlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow_Kremlin) (ice cream → Krem + a Lin(e) of people) – this would fit the hints in the comments by the OP to the Red Square.

Comment: @Omar is 7 correct too?

Comment: excellent @Glorfindel .. 7 is correct *applause*

Comment: What about my new guess for 16?

Comment: Wow  suitably impressed Sir

Answer (score 5):

Two more:

4:

> [Stonehenge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stonehenge)

12:

> [Vatican (City)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vatican_City)

and also:

10:

> [(Great) Smoky Mountains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Smoky_Mountains)

13:

> [Pyrenees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrenees)

Comment: well done. especially Pyrenees 

Answer (score 5):

Another: 
17:

> Yellowstone National Park

Answer (score 5):

1:

> Angel + fall + fall = [Angel Falls](https://whc.unesco.org/en/list/701/)

3:

> Mountain + fu + G = [Mount Fuji](http://whc.unesco.org/en/list/1418)

6:

> Kill + eye + mango + jar + O = [Kilimanjaro](https://whc.unesco.org/en/list/403)

Comment: very good Correct 

Answer (score 5):

9:

> Statue of Liberty (lie-bee-tea)

14:

> Great Barrier Reef (Beer-Ear)

19:

> Rockies (Rock-Eyes)

20:

> Chichen Itza (Chicken-Easter)

Comment: last one easter island

Comment: actually I was thinking Bar-ear-reef

Answer (score 5):

2:

> Eye, Full [moon], Toe, War [medal]
>  [The Eiffel Tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiffel_Tower)

8:

> Toe, War [medal], Pizza
>  [The (Leaning) Tower of Pisa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_Tower_of_Pisa)

Not particularly happy with this, but for number 11:

> Gran(d), [Adder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vipera_berus)
>  [Granada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granada)

Comment:  well done 

Answer (score 5):

18. Is it:

> Ghee cops (cheops) pyramids?

Comment:   i think that’s good enuf .. Ghee-sir-pyramids .. the second syllable cud be improved ☺️

Comment: @Omar Is that the correct answer then?

Comment: Oh sorry silly me .. yes they are one of the same Giza pyramids . Your journey differed to mine but we arrived at the same destination  

Answer (score 4):

Another one:

20.

> [Easter Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_Island)

Comment: This has also been submitted as an answer for 19... It could be either tbh

Comment: I like this one for 20 and JMP’s for 19 better!

Comment: Good point    ..

Answer (score 3):

19:

> Rapa Nui National Park (Easter Island)

Answer (score 2):

My answer to 11 (incorrect according to OP):

> [Grand Canyon National Park](https://whc.unesco.org/en/list/75) (1000-grand, snake-canyon)

Comment: Sorry Grand Canyon is incorrect - Red Square is kinda included already - stay tuned :)

Answer (score 2):

2. (wrong)

> Urban Historic Centre of Cienfuegos (See + N[ight] + Foo[t] + egos [ego boost because of a medal])

16. (wrong)

> Caves and Ice Age Art in the Swabian Jura (Ice eight)

Comment: excellent try but sorry incorrect

Comment: @Omar updated. Added my guess for 2.

Comment: another interesting answer but no (

Answer (score 2):

Best I can do for 18: (wrong)

> Sulaiman-Too Sacred Mountain (Sula (brand of butterscotch) - Man - 2 red mountains)

Comment: No man! You’ll kick yourself when revealed 

Answer (score 2):

18 guess (wrong):

> Margravial Opera House: (Butter -> **Marg**arine + **Avia**tor + Sydney **Opera House**)

Comment: I'm humbled by your knowledge of UNESCO world heritage sites, but sadly no *sorrowful emoji*

Answer (score 1):

The best I can do for 18:

> Monarch Butterfly Biosphere Reserve (**Butter** + Pilot for **Fly** + Up Up for **Biosphere**)

Comment: V Interesting try but no (

Answer (score 1):

For 18 (wrong):

> Lambini, the Birthplace of the Lord Buddha, in Nepal.

Comment:  no mate! Not sure how you can’t to that

Comment: butter -> buttah -> buddha, and then the red triangles look like the Nepalese flag.

Comment: Ah I see.. but there is a better answer ..

Answer (score 1):

18 perhaps:

> bermuda triangle

How?

> I got it from cutting "utt" out of butter for ber, pilot for the planes that sometimes go missing, and triangles for triangle.

Comment: First word - think synonym

Answer (score 1):

18:

> Risco Caido and the Sacred Mountains
>  (crisco can be used in place of butter?) c-RISCO - (pilot - aids in air travel) AID - sac-RED MOUNTAINS

Comment: Incorrect sorry but That’s a very interesting fact I’ve just learned , thank you .. and I live in Tenerife lol