# Another UNESCO World Heritage riddle

Tags: knowledge, visual, rebus, emoji

*This puzzle was inspired by [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/96702/emoji-puzzle-unesco-world-heritage-sites)*

> 1. ⛵$-$p
> 2. Long
> 3. a⚽u
> 4. Ak➕
> 5. $-$
> 6. of d $-$
> 7. ❄️ $-$  $+$ C

Answer (score 4):

Wikifying right away this time so we can collect all answers in one place.

1: ⛵−p

2: Long

> Ha + Long = **Ha Long**

3: a⚽u

> King + a + ball + u = **Kinabalu** (Park)

4: Ak➕

> Ak + sum = **Aksum**

5: −

> Red + tree - leaves = **Redwood** (National and State Parks)?

6:  of d −

> Ring + of + bro + d + garlic - lick = **Ring of Brodgar**

7: ❄️ −  + C

> Inuit Hunting Ground between Ice and Sea (?)

Comment: 7: Snowflake? + Eyes (ice?) + Castle? - Peach(?) + C